# Conservation of Magnetic Flux and vorticity in astrophysical plasmas

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics

I have a doubt about the conservation of magnetic flux in astrophysical plasmas, in particular in the presence of turbulent motions and vorticity (surely due to poor understanding of vector identities).

If vorticity is always conserved in the absence of viscosity (Kelvin's theorem):

$\frac{\partial\vec{\Omega}}{\partial t} = \nabla \times (\vec{v} \times \vec{\Omega})=0$

And magnetic flux is always conserved, with the similar induction equation:

$\frac{\partial\vec{H}}{\partial t} = \nabla \times (\vec{v} \times \vec{H})=0$

Now, the dynamo effect can spontaneously generate magnetic field in a plasma through turbulent motion, and how can this be justified without breaking conservation or Kelvin's theorem, if the same vector identity applies for vorticity?

Or does the dynamo effect merely amplify/dampen an already existing magnetic field?

Thank you in advance!